# How to use getSecret() in env variables using bicep?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

I want to fetch values from AKV and pass it into my module code. But getSecret() can be used only for string or objects which are part of the module. How do I pass the AKV values to my environment parameters?

```
resource containerAppEnvironment 'Microsoft.App/managedEnvironments@2022-11-01-preview' existing = {
  name: containerAppEnvironmentName
}

resource kv 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2023-02-01' existing = {
  name: kvName
  // scope: resourceGroup(subscriptionId, kvResourceGroup )
}

module postgresql '../../../../../../iac-modules/Infra-As-Code/Modules/Bicep/DBforPostgreSQL/flexibleServers.bicep' = {
  name: 'postgresql-flexibleServers'
  params: {
    namingConventionProperties: namingConventionProperties
    shortName: shortName
    location: location
    tags: tags
    administratorLogin: kv.getSecret('administratorLogin')
    administratorLoginPassword: kv.getSecret('administratorLoginPassword')
    postgresqlServerVersion: postgresqlServerVersion
    skuName: skuName
    skuTier: skuTier
    skuSizeGB: skuSizeGB
    availabilityZone: availabilityZone
    psqlMetadata : {
      sharedResourceGroup: sharedResourceGroupName
      privEndpointSubnetName: privEndpointSubnetName
      sharedVnetName: sharedVnetName
      pvtDnsZone: {
        resourceGroupName: privDnsSharedResourceGroup
        subscriptionId: privDnsSubscriptionId
        privateDnsZoneName: privateDnsZoneName
      }
    }
  }
}

module database '../../../../../../iac-modules/Infra-As-Code/Modules/Bicep/DBforPostgreSQL/Databases/database.bicep' = {
  name: 'postgresqlDb'
  params: {
    dbName : dbName
    postgresqlName: postgresql.name
    charset: charset
    collation: collation
  }
}

module ContainerApp '../../../../../../iac-modules/Infra-As-Code/Modules/Bicep/ContainerApps/containerApps.bicep' = {
  name: 'ContainerAppDeploy'
  params: {
    namingConventionProperties: namingConventionProperties
    location: location
    tags: tags
    shortName: shortName
    identityType: identityType
    containerAppEnvironmentName: containerAppEnvironment.id
    containerImage: containerImage
    useExternalIngress: useExternalIngress
    containerPort: containerPort
    containerResouceCpu: containerResouceCpu
    containerResouceMemory: containerResouceMemory
    containerAppName: containerAppName
    transportMethod: transportMethod
    environmentVariables: [
      {
        name: 'SONAR_JDBC_USERNAME'
        value: administratorLogin
      }
      {
        name: 'SONAR_JDBC_PASSWORD'
        value: administratorLoginPassword
      }
      {
        name: 'SONAR_JDBC_URL'
        value: 'jdbc:postgresql://${postgresql.outputs.postgresqlURL}:5432/sonarqube?user=${administratorLogin}&password=${administratorLoginPassword}&sslmode=require'
        //value: postgresql.outputs.postgresqlURL
        // jdbc:postgresql://lnos-devops-psql-sonarqube-dev.postgres.database.azure.com:5432/sonarqube?user=psqlAdmin&password=uGDk2LGfq82n3HFd&sslmode=require
      }
      {
        name: 'SONAR_SEARCH_JAVAADDITIONALOPTS'
        value: '-Dnode.store.allow_mmap=false'
      }
    ]
      maxReplicas: maxReplicas
      minReplicas: minReplicas
  }
  dependsOn: [
    postgresql
  ]
}
```

I tried creating object of environment variables but it didn't worked for me. Do anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Hi, what's the error message ? is it not working when using param / variables ?

Comment: what do you mean by env parameters?

Comment: Hi @Thomas I meant the `environmentVariables` array in module ContainersApp. If I want to add the value for SONAR_JDBC_USERNAME.

The error I get is in VS Studio Editor itself, that @secure() decorator can be use only with module parameters.

Comment: oh ok i see. yeah that wont work here. why not using kv vault reference in container app ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/manage-secrets?tabs=azure-portal#reference-secret-from-key-vault. or you could always pass the value as string and add it to the env variables inside the module

Comment: @Thomas Ohh!! Thank You for the information, but can I get to know how to do it in bicep?